# How to trace LoopBack Interface using Winpcap library in c/c++ program?

Tags: c, loopback, pcap, winpcap, sniffing

I want to sniff my **local device** using **winpcap** (#include "pcap.h") in c/c++. But when i list all my interfaces it doesn't show loopback interface. Can someone help me to write a code to sniff my own localhost for packet tracing.

Answer (score 0):

> But when i list all my interfaces it doesn't show loopback interface.

WinPcap doesn't *have* a loopback interface.

[Npcap](https://npcap.org) does; use it, instead.